# Multiple Domains django app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, settings

Django have nice sites framework, so i thought can it posissible to store on heroku app with multi-settings structure and join it with differents domains on one heroku instance?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you can use Django sites framework with Heroku if you set `SITE_ID = None`. In that case Django will automatically detect current site based on `request.get_host()` method. So you only have to add specific hosts in admin panel.

> The SITE_ID setting specifies the database ID of the Site object associated with that particular settings file. If the setting is omitted, the get_current_site() function will try to get the current site by comparing the domain with the host name from the request.get_host() method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/